# Remove period when cross-referencing a section

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing

I'm writing a paper for an IET conference, and they have provided the latex class [ecoc02](http://conferences.theiet.org/isp/-documents/isp-latex.cfm?type=zip) for formatting. In this format Sections appear with a period after the number:

1. Introduction

but when I reference the section, I also get an unwanted period after the reference. Can I easily remove the period when cross-referencing sections?

For example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{ecoc02}
\begin{document} 

\section{Introduction}
This is the introduction, Section \ref{sec:methods} is the methods section. Some conclusions are given in Section \ref{sec:conclusions}.

\section{Methods}\label{sec:methods}
This is the methods section. Section \ref{sec:method1} discusses the first result.

\subsection{Method 1}\label{sec:method1}
This is method 1.

\section{Conclusions}\label{sec:conclusions}
Something profound.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The class does `\renewcommand\thesection      {\@arabic\c@section.}` and this is causing the undesired period in cross-references; there are better ways to add the period in the sectional unit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The class does `\renewcommand\thesection {\@arabic\c@section.}` and this is causing the undesired period in cross-references; this seems a bad design choice
by the class author. If you want to avoid this, you can redefine `\thesection` to suppress the period and then you need to make some changes to `\thesubsection`, to the section entries in the ToC and to the section headings:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{IET02}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\bfseries}{\thesection.}{0.5em}{}
\renewcommand\cftsecaftersnum{.} 
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}

\begin{document} 
\tableofcontents
\section{Introduction}
This is the introduction, Section \ref{sec:methods} is the methods section. Some conclusions are given in Section \ref{sec:conclusions}.

\section{Methods}\label{sec:methods}
This is the methods section. Section \ref{sec:method1} discusses the first result.

\subsection{Method 1}\label{sec:method1}
This is method 1.

\section{Conclusions}\label{sec:conclusions}
Something profound.

\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't know however if you are allowed to use these packages. You should inform the conference organizers about this problem with the class.

Comment: That's great, thanks for the quick response. I'll send them an email later.